# Is there anyway to store textsize inside a drawable, that way dependend upon the screen size the main.xml will select the correct textsize?

Tags: android, text

I want my app to have the ability to run on multiple screen sizes and I was hoping I could store text size values inside the different drawable folders so the text would fit based on screen size. Or is there a better practice for this problem?

EX:
drawable-hdpi << textsize == 50

drawable-mdpi << textsize == 25

drawable-ldpi << textsize == 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by @wsanville was correct if you want a an identical look and it scales correct, however if for some reason you want completely different sizes.  For example, you are using a different layout on the tablet than you do on the phone and you want it to be a header on 1 and a subheader on the other.  Then I'd recommend you define different dimen folders.

```
 - values/dimens.xml
<dimen name="textSize">16sp</dimen>
 - values-large/dimens.xml
<dimen name="textSize">32sp</dimen>
 - values-xlarge/dimens.xml
<dimen name="textSize">32sp</dimen>
```

The above example would give you a small look on the phone and a large look on the tablets.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing do to would be to define your text size in `dp` (density independent pixels) or `sp` (scaled pixels).

Doing so, Android will automatically take account for the density by using the following calculations:

- ldpi = 0.75x
- mdpi = 1x (baseline)
- hdpi = 1.5x
- xhdpi = 2x

So, suppose you define your text as `12dp`. It will end up being 12 pixels on a medium density device, 18 pixels on a high, and so on.

Like alextsc notes, in the case of text sizes, it's best to use `sp` for your unit, because it will take account for a user preference for font size that was added in ICS. On lower versions of Android, `sp` is simply equivalent to `dp`.

Comment: It should be said that you should prefer `sp` over `dp` in any case. sp and dp are basically the same thing, the only difference is: sp considers the users font size preference and accessibility settings when calulating pixel dimensions. That is never a bad thing and some users may depend on it.